# How can I sync my Ubuntu One music to an mp3 player?

Tags: sync, music, ubuntu-one

Is there a way to automatically sync just my Ubuntu One music (and not the rest of my Music Library) to my Sansa Fuze mp3 player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:
Placed the following `autorun` script in the root directory of my mp3 player, and run it when I plug it in.

```
#!/bin/bash

# sync Ubuntu One music
rsync -avz -stats --ignore-existing ~/.ubuntuone/Purchased\ from\ Ubuntu\ One/ MUSIC/Ubuntu\ One
```

Comment: found via a search for 'autorun'.  I have yet to get autorun to work with my UMS device.  This will be the subject of a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://launchpad.net/rhythmbox-playlist-sync Which allows you to Sync playlists with external devices. You could use the Purchased Music list and sync only that list with your portable device.

*I have not tested this actual plugin and can not speak to its validity. This is simply a hypothetical-type answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible at the moment as there are no MP3-player clients of UbuntuOne.

However, you could try the synchronisation feature for music players of Banshee. This feature would synchronise your player each time you would connect it to your Banshee-running computer with the playlist you selected, or your whole music library.
I'm not sure if Rhythmbox has a similar functionality.